The simplest way to prove that $S^n$ is not homotopy equivalent to $ \Omega S^{n+1}$
Looking at $\pi_n$ of $S^n$ and $\Omega S^{n+1}$ does not help with telling them apart, so it seems natural to ask whether they are homotopy equivalent. I know that using the Serre spectral sequence to compute homology groups of $\Omega S^{n+1}$ is a way to see that this cannot be the case, but it seems like an overkill for this particular question.
Additionally, I am aware that $\Omega S^{n+1}$ has the same homotopy type as the James reduced product $J(S^n)$, though I am unsure if this fact is useful here.

"Looking at the homotopy groups of $S^n$ and $\Omega S^{n + 1}$ does not help with telling them apart" no, it absolutely does. In degrees $> n$, the homotopy groups of these spaces will generally differ (otherwise the problem of computing $\pi_k S^n$ would suddenly become a lot easier :-). But that's probably not easier than just doing the SerSS computation. I'd also not say that it's overkill, but maybe someone can offer a more elementary approach.

Technically that's correct, but better say "Looking at $\pi_n$ [...]" :)

Knowing that $\Omega S^{n+1}\simeq J(S^n)$ is definitely useful. The cohomology ring of $J(S^n)$ is the divided polynomial algebra for even $n$ and divided polynomial algebra tensored with an exterior algebra for odd $n$, whereas the cohomology ring structure for sphere is quite simple. I would say that this approach is simpler than the spectral sequence calculation.

Thank you @Kevin.S, I didn't know that. For anyone interested this is Proposition 3.22 in Hatcher. So we have two solutions. Still wondering if there exists a more elementary one. But maybe I should get over it and go study spectral sequences and cohomology rings :)

Rational homotopy groups should do it, right? That is still typically a Serre SS calculation, but I think it's a pretty easy one.

If you want to conclude anything from $\pi_k$ s of $S^n$ or $\Omega S^{n+1}$, you might want use some kind of fiber or cofiber sequence. There is a fibration involving these two given by: $S^n \hookrightarrow \Omega S^{n+1} \to \Omega S^{2n+1}$. But construction of this fibration uses the James construction (this is used to prove the EHP sequence). Even if you use this fibration you can see that for higher values of $k$ you can't really conclude anything about their homotopy groups. So, I don't think using spectral sequence is a `overkill' here.

The loop space of $S^{n+1}$ and $S^n$ are not homotopically equivalent.
The homotopy groups of the loop space of $S^{n+1}$ are $\pi_i(\Omega S^{n+1}) = \pi_{i+1}(S^{n+1})$, which are trivial for $i < n$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ for $i = n$. The homotopy groups of the loop space of $S^n$ are $\pi_i(\Omega S^n) = \pi_{i+1}(S^n)$, which are trivial for $i < n-1$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ for $i = n-1$.
Since the homotopy groups of the two loop spaces are different, they cannot be homotopically equivalent.
You can find the homotopy group of loop spaces as a way to stepping one more than the homotopy group of before.
There is nothing to think difficulty.
It is enough to compare each homotopy groups of them.

I think you got your degree shift backward. You'll need to go to the "non-obvious" homotopy groups above degre $n$ to see a difference.

Okay. I'll check then
